# How do I fix unix so that I can use the arrow keys in a terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard

Before I was able to use the <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arrow keys to cycle through previous commands, but now when I press a directional key it outputs "^[[A". I'm running a bash shell. How do I fix this?

Comment: Whats your terminal?

Comment: How would I find that information?

Comment: @please: I expect that you are using a terminal emulator which is what you might call a "shell window" on whatever system you are running. As this is almost certainly so, your probably have a Help -> About menu selection: what does that say? What operating system are you running your terminal on? (e.g. Windows, MacOS, Debian, etc.)

Comment: There are many possibilities: your terminal is misconfigured (unlikely), your shell has wrong ideas about your terminal (less unlikely), you're getting a shell other than bash, etc. To start diagnosing, describe your OS (distribution, version, …), how you start a shell window, and the output of `echo $TERM; ps -p $$ -p $PPID` in a shell window.

Comment: What do the commands `echo $TERM` and `toe` print?

Comment: I have the same problem, running GNOME Terminal (using xterm) as a non-root user.

Answer (score 2):

The likely problem is that bash (**not** a full-screen program) is using termcap (for full-screen programs) and not accommodating the use of application mode in the key bindings.

The problem can be solved by one of these approaches:

- hardcoding bindings in `.inputrc` (the route taken by most bash users)
- choosing a terminal description which (like `linux` and `rxvt`) does not use application mode, or
- improving bash so that (like the Debian package for `zsh`), it knows how to accept keys automatically whether they use normal or application mode.

Further reading:

- [Shell Tricks: .inputrc binding fun](http://brettterpstra.com/2015/07/09/shell-tricks-inputrc-binding-fun/), illustrating hardcoding
- [cursor keys not working on console](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-questions/2013-August/252668.html), mentions `xterm-noapp` terminal description.
- [My cursor keys do not work](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#cursor_appmode) (ncurses FAQ)
- [Special keys](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Special-Keys) (xterm manual, contrasting bash and ksh)

Answer (score 1):

Try typing

```
set -o emacs
```

Comment: That would be my advice, too. Seems like vi mode is enabled in the shell.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Already set. Still getting A B C S instead of arrow movement.