# Why END key does not have terminfo entry?

Tags: terminal, ncurses, termcap, terminfo

On a Debian system pressing `END` key generates `^[[F`:

```
$ showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^[[F     27 0033 0x1b
         91 0133 0x5b
         70 0106 0x46
```

But why this keychord is not in *terminfo*?

```
$ infocmp -1 | grep end
kend=\EOF,
```

Nevertheless, *ncurses* manages to correctly recognize it as `KEY_END`. How?

`TERM` is `xterm-256color`

BTW, what is the motivation behind having `kend` and `end` instead of just `end` ? (the same for `khome` and `home`)

**EDIT**

As said in the comment of Johan Myréen, `khome` string is the sequence pressing the Home key produces. But on Debian pressing Home key produces `home`. Why?

```
$ showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^[[H     27 0033 0x1b
         91 0133 0x5b
         72 0110 0x48
```

```
$ infocmp -1 | grep home
    home=\E[H,
    khome=\EOH,
```

Comment: The difference between `home` and `khome` is that the `khome` string is the sequence pressing the Home key produces, whereas `home` string is the sequence that should be sent to the terminal to move the cursor to the home position. To my knowledge, terminfo does not define an `end` capability, just `kend`.

Comment: @JohanMyréen Could you please explain what is "home position" of a cursor with an example? And why `kend` is defined as `\EOF` in *terminfo*, whereas the terminal generates `\E[F`? Is this a bug in Debian's *terminfo*? And how *ncurses* manages to detect it as `KEY_END` nevertheless?

Comment: The home position is the upper left corner of the screen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Johan Myréen's answer was close, but not exactly the problem: most of the terminal emulators which you will use have *normal* and *application* modes for special keys.  Terminal descriptions are written for **one** mode, which corresponds to what a full-screen application uses.  Other applications (such as an interactive **shell**) typically do not initialize the screen to use *application* mode.  Bash is an example of that.

In *normal* mode, xterm and similar terminals send <kbd>*escape*</kbd><kbd>**`[`**</kbd> (CSI) while in *application* mode, their keypads send <kbd>*escape*</kbd><kbd>**`O`**</kbd> (SS3).  In terminfo syntax, that *escape* is `\E`.  So `infocmp` is showing you that the description uses application mode.  The **`home`** capability is sent **to** the terminal, telling it how to move the cursor to the *home* position (upper left), and is not the same as **`khome`** (sent **from** the terminal using the keyboard).

Full-screen applications (such as those using ncurses) *may* send the terminal-capability strings for initializing the keypad.  Some terminal descriptions do put the terminal into application mode, some don't.

The use of **`kend`** versus **`end`** is a naming convention: in terminfo by convention any name beginning with **k** refers to a special key (function key, cursor key, keypad-key) to make it clear that these are strings to be read by an application.  For example, **`kcub1`** (cursor-backward **key**) is distinct from **`cub1`** (move the cursor back one column).

ncurses recognizes the key as **`KEY_END`** because the application you are using will call the [`keypad`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-keypad) function to initialize the terminal using the `smkx` (the mnemonic means "start keyboard-transmit mode").  That may/may not actually turn on application mode.  Linux console's terminal description does not, xterm's does.

In principle, you could use [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) for switching the mode (and get different results from `showkey`):

```
$ showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^[[H     27 0033 0x1b
         91 0133 0x5b
         72 0110 0x48
^C        3 0003 0x03
^D        4 0004 0x04
$ tput smkx
$ showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^[OH     27 0033 0x1b
         79 0117 0x4f
         72 0110 0x48
```

As a complication, curses will recognize only one name for a string.  Some terminals (such as xterm) emulate older hardware terminals using different names for the keys on the editing keypad.  In the xterm FAQ listed below, there's the possibility of naming that "Home" key "Insert"...

Further reading:

- [How do I fix unix so that I can use the arrow keys in a terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3422/how-do-i-fix-unix-so-that-i-can-use-the-arrow-keys-in-a-terminal/261741#261741)
- [My home/end keys do not work](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#home_end_keys) (ncurses FAQ)
- [Why doesn't my keypad work?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_keypad) (xterm FAQ)
- [Keypad and Function Keys](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Keypad-and-Function-Keys) (terminfo manual)
- [User-Defined Capabilities](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-User-Defined-Capabilities) (terminfo manual, commenting on other use of "k")
- [Keypad mode](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Keypad-mode) (`getch` manual page)

Comment: Yes, I'm using `keypad` function. But with the question "how ncurses manages to detect it as `KEY_END`" I meant "how `keypad` decodes `^[[F` into `kend`" (considering that `keypad` uses *terminfo* database to interpret the keychords). If I understood correctly, this happens because `showkey -a` is in cursor mode, whereas ncurses application is in application mode.

Comment: `showkey` doesn't switch between normal/application modes.  It's a Linux-specific program, making assumptions about the Linux console, rather than using the terminal database

Comment: If `showkey` doesn't switch between modes, then it uses some default state, whatever it may be called. The point is that `showkey` prints `^[[F`, not `^[OF`, which lead to my confusion. (I just used `showkey` to visually represent the actual keychord which is being sent by the terminal by pressing on a keyboard button, without suspecting that there may be some subtleties involved.)

Comment: Yes, that's "normal" mode (the usual way of referring to this).  You could of course initialize your terminal using `tput smkx` and get different results.

Comment: I think that there is a bug in `less` utility: it puts itself into application mode, but then fails to interpret keypad enter key. Should I submit a bug report? (You may check this by starting `less` and pressing keypad enter key after typing `/` - it will output `ESCOM`, instead of doing what enter key must do.)

Comment: It probably simply does not lookup the `kent` (actually termcap *`@8`*) value, and relies upon matching the termcap strings vs having something to ignore escape sequences that it doesn't recognize.  But that's a whole topic by itself :-)

Comment: What should be done to fix `less`, if not for upstream, then at least for local use? Just want to bring a little sanity to this mess...

Comment: Then there is another problem: entry for `^[[H` **is** in *terminfo* (but it must not be there, because it is used in "normal" mode), while `^[[F`, which is also used in "normal" mode, is not present in *terminfo* (considering the fact that terminfo contains entries only for "application" mode). Should I report a bug to debian *terminfo* maintainers?

Comment: see second paragraph.

Comment: For example, `bash` uses "normal" mode, which is not described in *terminfo* database. So, keychords like `^[[F` need to be **hard-coded** in `readline`, which is used by `bash`. But this defeats the whole purpose of having *terminfo* database in the first place...

Answer (score 6):

The problem with the Home key is that physical terminals and later the terminal emulators that emulate them have two modes: normal and Application Mode, and the escape sequences are different depending on the mode the terminal is in. Terminfo does not cope well with this. In normal mode (aka "Cursor Mode") the End key escape sequence is `ESC [ F`, in Application mode `ESC O F`. Googling for this problem reveals the whole mess.

**Edit** From the terminfo source:

"The VT100 series terminals have cursor ("arrows") keys which can operate
in two different modes: Cursor Mode and Application Mode.  Cursor Mode
is the reset state, and is assumed to be the normal state.  Application
Mode is the "set" state.  In Cursor Mode, the cursor keys transmit
"Esc [ {code}" sequences, conforming to ANSI standards.  In Application
Mode, the cursor keys transmit "Esc O " sequences.  Application Mode
was provided primarily as an aid to the porting of VT52 applications.  It is
assumed that the cursor keys are normally in Cursor Mode, and expected that
applications such as vi will always transmit the  string.  Therefore,
the definitions for the cursor keys are made to match what the terminal
transmits after the  string is transmitted.  If the  string
is a null string or is not defined, then cursor keys are assumed to be in
"Cursor Mode", and the cursor keys definitions should match that assumption,
else the application may fail.  It is also expected that applications will
always transmit the  string to the terminal before they exit."

Comment: What is the procedure of switching to "application mode"? Is it done by *ncurses*?