# Why terminfo entries do not follow convention?

Tags: terminal, terminfo

*terminfo* database contains entries, describing "application mode". By convention, entries which correspond to buttons, pressed on keyboard, start with `\EO` (this is done so that applications which do not perform initialization will know in which mode terminal is initialized by default - "normal" or "application") and are named with **k** prefix. But for example, on Debian 10 ( `/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-256color`) this is not true:

```
$ infocmp -1|grep 'kf[0-9]='
kf1=\EOP,
kf2=\EOQ,
kf3=\EOR,
kf4=\EOS,
kf5=\E[15~,
kf6=\E[17~,
kf7=\E[18~,
kf8=\E[19~,
kf9=\E[20~,
```

Is this a bug in terminfo database?

Comment: What convention are you referring to? There's no convention that function key escape sequences start with `\EO`. `\E[` is a very common prefix, `\EO` is a bit of a legacy one.

Comment: @Gilles I'm referring to this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383087/143661

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a broad topic...

Most (not all) terminals are configurable, with the ones you're familiar with responding to control sequences which provide *application* modes for the *cursor*, *editing* and *numeric* keypad keys.  You may notice that I didn't list *function keys*.

The terminfo database describes a particular configuration of the terminal.

Your example shows a configuration used for `xterm` to provide a VT100-style numeric keypad.  The typical PC keyboard hasn't enough keys to match the VT100 keypad (because although it has 4 keys in the "right" place, <kbd>*NumLock*</kbd> is treated specially), and (since VT100s never **had** function keys), it was convenient to assign that top row to the first 4 PC function keys.

With `xterm`, that's configurable anyway, but as noted, terminfo entries describe a *particular* configuration.

You'll find that configuration copied by terminal emulators which don't actually provide a VT100-compatible numeric keypad, just to imitate [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html).

That's summarized in the xterm FAQ (for other terminals, typically it isn't documented at all):

- [Why doesn't my keypad work?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_keypad) (VT100 keypads discussed)
- [Why can't I use the cursor keys in (whatever) shell?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_arrows) (application mode)
- [Keypad and Function Keys](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Keypad-and-Function-Keys) (terminfo manual, which doesn't mention a "convention")